# Does a Magus' Weapon Enchancement Bonus Stack With An Existing Bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I know you can stack abilities such as Frost and Flaming, but what about the numerical bonus?

If you have a +1 Flaming Longsword, can a Magus then enchance it with 1 point to becoe a +2 Flaming Frost Longsword? Or just a +1 Flaming Frost Longsword?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [as stated in the rule](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Arcane-Pool-Su-).

> At 1st level, a magus can expend 1 point from his arcane pool as a swift action to grant any weapon he is holding a +1 enhancement bonus for 1 minute. For every four levels beyond 1st, the weapon gains another +1 enhancement bonus, to a maximum of +5 at 17th level. These bonuses can be added to the weapon, ***stacking with existing weapon enhancement*** to a maximum of +5. Multiple uses of this ability do not stack with themselves.