# How does Divine Weapon Bond (Paladin) work with Sacred Avenger?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, paladin

According to Sacred Avenger:

> This +3 cold iron longsword becomes a +5 holy defiant cold iron
> longsword in the hands of a paladin or a lawful good mythic creature.
> If the creature wielding this weapon is a paladin with mythic tiers,
> she can also grant the weapon the brilliant energy special ability on
> command. Dismissing the brilliant energy ability is a free action.

According to Ultimate Equipment:

> - Modified Bonus = Enhancement Bonus + Special Ability Bonus
> - Modified Bonus cannot exceed 10
> - Weapon can’t have an enhancement bonus higher than +5

Is Sacred Avenger exempt from this rule and how does Divine Weapon Bond (Paladin) interact with it?

Answer (score 4):

### Holy Avenger is an exception; Divine Bond is not

In the hands of a paladin, or mythic LG creature, Holy Avenger is a +9 weapon (5 enhancement, +2 *holy*, +2 *defiant*). As noted in [another question's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72383/28326), this only leaves room for a +1 equivalent ability from Divine Bond. To cite the relevant rule:

> ...modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus special ability bonus equivalents, including those from character abilities and spells)...

As is always the case, specific trump general. In this case, Holy Avenger says that a Mythic Paladin can also add *brilliant energy* (+4) on Command, so they can. In this case (until the effect is dismissed), Holy Avenger is a "+13" weapon and gains no benefit from Divine Bond.